# What is the best way to check if a tuple has any empty/None values in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, is-empty

What is the best/most efficient way to check if all tuple values? Do I need to iterate over all tuple items and check or is there some even better way?

For example:

```
t1 = (1, 2, 'abc')
t2 = ('', 2, 3)
t3 = (0.0, 3, 5)
t4 = (4, 3, None)
```

Checking these tuples, every tuple except `t1`, should return True, meaning there is so called empty value.

P.S. there is this question: [Test if tuple contains only None values with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294383/test-if-tuple-contains-only-none-values-with-python), but is it only about None values

Comment: Oh, that would do :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's very easy:

```
not all(t1)
```

returns `False` only if all values in `t1` are non-empty/nonzero and not `None`. `all` short-circuits, so it only has to check the elements up to the first empty one, which makes it very fast.

Comment: Also works for `namedtuple` (since it's a subclass, of course) =)

Comment: @TimPietzcke I think it also checks for False (Boolean) value, if one of the value in tuple is False all(t1) will return False

Comment: @sau: Yes, `False` *is* `0`.

Answer (score 22):

An answer using all has been provided:

```
not all(t1)
```

However in a case like t3, this will return True, because one of the values is 0:

```
t3 = (0.0, 3, 5)
```

The 'all' built-in keyword checks if all values of a given iterable are values that evaluate to a negative boolean (False). 0, 0.0, '' and None all evaluate to False.

If you only want to test for None (as the title of the question suggests), this works:

```
any(map(lambda x: x is None, t3))
```

This returns True if any of the elements of t3 is None, or False if none of them are.

Answer (score 5):

If by any chance want to check if there is an empty value in a tuple containing tuples like these:

```
t1 = (('', ''), ('', ''))
t2 = ((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0))
t3 = ((None, None), (None, None))
```

you can use this:

```
not all(map(lambda x: all(x), t1))
```

Otherwise if you want to know if there is at least one positive value, then use this:

```
any(map(lambda x: any(x), t1))
```

Answer (score 4):

For your specific case, you can use `all()` function , it checks all the values of a list are true or false, please note in python `None` , empty string and `0` are considered false.

So -

```
>>> t1 = (1, 2, 'abc')
>>> t2 = ('', 2, 3)
>>> t3 = (0.0, 3, 5)
>>> t4 = (4, 3, None)
>>> all(t1)
True
>>> all(t2)
False
>>> all(t3)
False
>>> all(t4)
False
>>> if '':
...     print("Hello")
...
>>> if 0:
...     print("Hello")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
None in (None,2,"a")
```

True

```
None in (1,2,"a")
```

False

```
"" in (1,2,"")
```

True

```
"" in (None,2,"a")
```

False

```
import numpy

np.nan in (1,2, np.nan)
```

True

```
np.nan in (1,2, "a")
```

False