# How to clean data without pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I have to use python to clean data for easier analysis, however, I cannot use pandas in this case
the requirement and expectation are as below:

```
actual = preprocess([
            ('Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Fare'),
            ('no', '3', 'Braund Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', '22', '7.25'),
            ('Dead', '3', 'Braund Ms. Maria', 'Female', '21', ''),
            ('Yes', '1', 'Cumings Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'F', '38', '71.28'),
            ('', '3', 'Vander Planke Miss. Augusta', 'female', '', ''),
            ('Dead', '4', 'Lennon Mr. Denis', 'male', '13', '15.5')])

expected = (
                ('Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Fare'),
                [
                    (False, 3, 'Braund Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', 22.0, 7.25),
                    (False, 3, 'Braund Ms. Maria', 'female', 21.0, 25.0),
                    (True, 1, 'Cumings Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'female', 38.0, 71.28),
                    ('', 3, 'Vander Planke Miss. Augusta', 'female', '', 25.0), 
                    (False, 4, 'Lennon Mr. Denis', 'male', 13.0, 15.5)]
                ]
           )
```

Can you please give some advises in this case?

Comment: Not enough info. Why are the 4th and the 5th data lines not included in the expected output? What are your rules for converting the 1st column to a boolean value? Etc...

Comment: sorry, I probably miss out the last row. the rules are: (1) Survived - boolean, (2) Plass - int, (3) Name - string, (4) Gender - string (male and female only), (5) age - float, (6) fare - float

Comment: I can figure out that the 1st column is to be converted into a boolean. What I was asking is your rules for changing the strings to True or False. BTW, you're missing two rows in your expected output, not one.

Comment: Yes for True and no/dead for false. ('', 3, 'Vander Planke Miss. Augusta', 'female', '', 25.0),
            (False, 4, 'Lennon Mr. Denis', 'male', 13.0, 15.5)])

Comment: What are the rules for substituting missing values? In your example, a missing 'Fare' was replaced by '25.0'. Is that a general rule? What's with missing ages or missing 'Survived' status?

Comment: This is quite broad/vague. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Some information is missing (e.g. how to handle missing values? or should incomplete entries be filtered out? do you need the result to be sorted or not?), but I'll attempt an answer nonetheless:

To achieve your desired outcome of converting the type and/or content of your tuple 'columns', you need to map and/or typecast the old values to new ones.

---

**Mapping the strings**

You can do different approaches to map different input values to a range of output values. I'll use two in my answer: (1) `if ... else` statements and (2) a python way of doing a `switch ... case` statement.

In order to get a `bool` value from the different possible entries for 'Survived', I used approach (2). For this you set up a dictionary with your mappings and then get the appropriate entry from it for each of your candidates (see [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)). You can combine this with the string `lower()` function so that you can disregard case ([How do I lowercase a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-do-i-lowercase-a-string-in-python)). You can add also a default value that should be used in case the key can not be found in the dict, in my example below, I use `None`.

Example:

```
entry = 'NO'

switcher_survived = {
    'no': False,
    'dead': False,
    'yes': True
}

result = switcher_survived.get(entry.lower(), None)
```

The same approach can be used to set the gender based on the different input possibilities.

---

**Typecasting**

For the numbers, you can simply cast them to the desired type. However, this will only work if the string contains a number that can successfully be cast. Note that in your example, you have entries with an empty string which will lead to a `ValueError` when you try to cast. So you need to check that and may again want default to some value. I use `nan = float('NaN')` as this is a nice way of maintainig the correct type without using additional packages (see [Assigning a variable NaN in python without numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19374254/14015737)).

Example:

```
nan = float('NaN') 

entry = '2.5'

result = (float(entry) if float(entry) != "" else nan)
```

I'm using a one-line if-then-else statement here (see [Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line)), because that is beneficial for the full example at the end.

---

**Putting it together**

```
actual = [
        ('Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Fare'),
        ('no', '3', 'Braund Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', '22', '7.25'),
        ('Dead', '3', 'Braund Ms. Maria', 'Female', '21', ''),
        ('Yes', '1', 'Cumings Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'F', '38', '71.28'),
        ('', '3', 'Vander Planke Miss. Augusta', 'female', '', ''),
        ('Dead', '4', 'Lennon Mr. Denis', 'male', '13', '15.5')]


nan = float('NaN')

switcher_survived = {
    'no': False,
    'dead': False,
    'yes': True
}

switcher_gender = {
    'male': 'male',
    'm': 'male',
    'female': 'female',
    'f': 'female'
}

def process(lst):
    result = []
    current = 1
    while current < len(lst):
        tuple = (switcher_survived.get(lst[current][0].lower(),''),
                 int(lst[current][1]),
                 lst[current][2],
                 switcher_gender.get(lst[current][3].lower(),''),
                 (float(lst[current][4]) if lst[current][4] != "" else ''),
                 (float(lst[current][5]) if lst[current][5] != "" else 25.0)
                )
        result.append(tuple)
        current += 1
    return [lst[0], result]

expected = process(actual)

print(expected)
```

Some remarks:

- In this final example, I have changed the default value for the column 'Fare' to 25.0, as to conform with your expected outcome.
- For the same reason, I have also changed the default values for 'Survived', 'Gender' and 'Age' to the empty string `''` instead of `None` respectively `NaN`. Please note that this violates your own requirements, as the empty string is obviously not of type `bool` or `float`. This may have implications when you work with the data later. Especially, the empty string in column 'Survived' may be silently evaluated to `False`.
- To filter out incomplete data, you could change the default values back to `None` and `NaN` and only add complete rows to your final data set. For that, you could check if any of the tuples' fields are `None` (see [What is the best way to check if a tuple has any empty/None values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154372/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-tuple-has-any-empty-none-values-in-python)):

  ```
       if not any(map(lambda x: (x is None) or (x is nan), tuple)):
           result.append(tuple)
  ```
- If you wanted to sort the list by an arbitrary column, you could use a lambda fuction as sortkey (see [Syntax behind sorted(key=lambda: ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda)) before you return the result. E.g. to sort by the name:

  ```
   result = sorted(result, key=lambda tuple: tuple[2])
  ```